# Nuxt.js to make a copy of images uploaded in CMS during generate

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi

I've been using Nuxt.js for a bit now and used the great @bazzite/nuxt-optimized-images to create .webp, compress images, inline small ones and svgs during static files generation.

I have now started implementing an Headless CMS, Strapi in this case, and all the images will be uploaded via Strapi itself.

What I am understanding now it's that every image will be a request to the CMS, losing the possibility to compress my images during "generate".

Is this the correct way, or is there a way to create a copy of the images, inside a nuxt folder, during `nuxt generate`, and still make use of the optimization plugin? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently Nuxt does not have such functionality so far.